# Pandas to Specify Ordered Categorical data type at read_excel with converters

Tags: python, pandas

I am importing data from Excel into Pandas dataframe, and would like to specify ordered categorical data type during read_excel(). I expect subsequent pivoting of this data will respect the ordering, however it does not.

I can convert data type to Categorical *after* read_excel(), however I much prefer if it can be defined at converters during data import.

**Attempt 1:**

```
conv = {
    "COS_PACKAGE": lambda x: x.astype(pd.Categorical, 
                    categories=["Convergence", "Versatile", "Performance"], 
                    ordered=True)
}

df = pd.read_excel(r"data.xlsx", sheetname="DATA", converters=conv)
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
conv = {
    "COS_PACKAGE": lambda x: x.astype("categories", 
                    categories=["Convergence", "Versatile", "Performance"], 
                    ordered=True)
}

df = pd.read_excel(r"data.xlsx", sheetname="DATA", converters=conv)
```

**EDIT:**

Per comment request, this is how I convert to Categorical after data import, which works.

```
df["COS_PACKAGE"] = df["COS_PACKAGE"].astype("category",
                categories=["Convergence", "Versatile", "Performance"], 
                ordered=True)
```

Comment: What does the code that actually works look like?

Comment: In the latest version you can pass `dtype={'COS_PACKAGE': 'category'}` to `read_excel`  but I don't think that allows passing other arguments.